# Why does focus change while changing visibility?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

I am having issue with focus in winform, while I am changing visibility elements.

I am working on magazine reader app, and in winform I have bitmap and also two arrows which are changing site of magazine. But when the focus is changed, there starts a sharpening thread for bitmap and as the arrows are visible only on mouse move I am changing their visibility. And right there is my problem, when I change their visibility I lose focus from bitmap.

So please, is it posible to do change of visibility without changing of focus?

Comment: what are the two arrows? winform buttons?

Answer (score 0):

When you change visibly set the focus on the bitmap using [Control.Focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx), also set the property [TabStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabstop.aspx) to false for the 2 arrows.